# Unlock the SMS Limit on Android Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, sms

On Android, there's an SMS Limit that prevents a new message from being sent after a certain amount of messages have been sent in a certain period. Due to a personal need, I need to send more than the limit by unlocking it.

I already tried downloading apps from the Play Store that unlock SMS but no luck, although I completed the required prerequisites, seems like it's not working on Marshmallow. I also tried using ADB command, but the `Settings.db` was not found in provider settings.

How to unlock the SMS limit on Android Marshmallow?

Comment: Are you sure the limit is Android imposed rather than carrier-imposed?  I've never heard of an SMS limit on Android.

Comment: This may fix (not tried by me ) - https://www.xda-developers.com/increase-the-sms-limit-on-android/

Answer (score 1):

This method work on a non-rooted phone, I use it on Android 7/8:

1. On the phone, install [Settings Database Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by4a.setedit22) and open it
2. On the PC, install the driver for your phone, then connect to the phone using a USB cable
3. Download [this zip file containing a folder with minimal ADB](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7A3BdzmCcZTZmtweWRCMVhmMHc/view) and extract it to a folder
4. Open a command prompt and browse to the extracted directory
5. Type `adb devices` to check if the phone has been detected by the PC. If the status is "unauthorized", a pop-up should appear on the phone, accept it to allow ADB to communicate with it
6. Type

   ```
   adb shell pm grant by4a.setedit22 android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
   ```

   to allow the app to overwrite Android settings
7. Restart the phone
8. Open the app and add a new setting in these categories: `system`, `secure`, `global`. Push "+Add new settings" button on the top, then input `sms_outgoing_check_max_count` with value `99999`
9. Restart the phone

And now you can send a lot of messages.